# How to run IIS apppool recycle from powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, iis, cmd

I want to run the apppool recycle from a ps1 file using this:

```
#****** Variables
[String] $AppPoolName = $Global:Params['IIS_App_Pool_Name'] 
#$AppPoolName Contains the correct App Pool value from my IIS

[String] $WD=[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%WINDIR%")
[String] $appcmd = "$WD\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"
&$appcmd list APPPOOL

iex $appcmd recycle apppool $AppPoolName
```

But i got this error:

A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'recycle'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close, you just need to quote the entire string you pass to `iex`, otherwise it'll try and parse anything after `$appcmd` as parameters:

```
iex "$appcmd recycle apppool $AppPoolName"
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! Now the error is that i dont have permission to read configuration... i want to create a batch file that calls this ps1 file in administrator mode...